# TypeError from trying to resolve CORS error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, cors

I have `[Vue warn] TypeError` from trying to resolve CORS error.

Here is my code saving data to server.

```
saveToServer() {
  // Upload Code
  let formData: any = new FormData()
  formData.append(
    '0c42819f7026a5b7f407c011c0b9523dad249b9ceef29cddcc5140b6ab922867',
    ''
  )
  formData.append(
    'robot_file',
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.robot)]),
    `${this.taskName}.json`
  )
  formData.append(
    'robot_json',
    new Blob([this.robot.toRobot(0)]),
    `${this.taskName}.robot`
  )

  axios
    .post(
      'http://ideasolutions.co.kr/bpm/common/insertRpaProcessByDeviceList',
      formData,
      { headers: formData.getHeaders() }
    )
    .then((data: any) => {
      console.log('Upload End')
      console.log(data)
    })
}
```

To resolve CORS error, I added

```js
axios.post('', formData, {headers: formData.getHeaders()}, ...)
```

but it didn't work.

After adding that code, CORS warning was gone, but TypeError came.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: formData.getHeaders is not a function"

found in

---> <VBtn>
       <VAppBar>
         <ModelCanvas> at src/components/designer/ModelCanvas.vue
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

```
TypeError: formData.getHeaders is not a function
    at VueComponent.ModelCanvas.saveToServer (ModelCanvas.vue?ba42:162)
    at click (ModelCanvas.vue?4f3d:93)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:3017)
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:1815)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:3017)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:3716)
    at VueComponent.click (vuetify.js?ed19:2564)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:3017)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:1815)
    at HTMLButtonElement.original_1._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js?c320:7473)
```

Comment: The error is clear.  `getHeaders` is not a function.  It also did not solve your CORS error. This error has halted your code execution before the CORS error could happen.  Both problems now exist.  You can see [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) API has no `getHeaders` function.  I believe you probably read some node.js documentation. That's a different FormData, not usable on the frontend.  There's not enough information about the CORS error to help.  [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors) is a good resource for troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `FormData` don't have function `getHeaders`.

To resolve CORS error, you can't do it from front-end (client-side), you must handle it from server-side by enable client's origin on server.

If your server base on express.js, please reference [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: I saw this problem milion times, and argued about this hundered of times with backend developers. When you see a CORS error, simply say it's not on my side, and persists on this say until the problem solves.